# How to render a plot from a list of multiple objects on ShinyApp

Tags: r, list, plot, render, shiny

I have a function Identify_IP() that returns a list of 1- dataframe 
2-ggplot. I need to renderTable and renderPlot in ShinyApp. This shinyApp code renders only the dataframe. But I can't render the plot. Any help?

```
library(shiny)

source('InflectionP2.R', local = TRUE)

runApp(
  list(
    ui = fluidPage(
      titlePanel("Upload your file"),
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
          fileInput('file1', 'Choose xls file',
                    accept = c(".XLS")),

          actionButton("btn", "Update Table"),
          actionButton("btn1", "Display Plot"),

          downloadButton('downloadData', 'Download')
        ),

      mainPanel(
        tableOutput('what'),
        plotOutput('pl'))
    )
    )
    ,

    server = function(input, output, session){

      dataOP <- reactive({
    inFile <- input$file1
    if (is.null(input$file1))
      return(NULL)

  Identify_IP(read.table(inFile$datapath))
  list(tble = df1, txt = inflection_points, plt = p )
  })


  observeEvent(input$btn, output$what <- renderTable({dataOP()$tble}))

  observeEvent(input$btn1, output$pl <- renderPlot({
    plot(dataOP()$plt)
  }))              
     }
      ))
```

Comment: You will have to plot `dataOP()$p`, e.g. using `plot()`

Comment: Can you give more details? How is that different from what I already did?

Comment: And btw, I don't think the list works, as I tried dataOP()$df1 and didn't render the table. So I settled for dataOP()

Comment: Yes, the list probably needs to be moved inside the `reactive({ ... })`. Just try something like `plot(dataOP()$p)` or however you want your plot to look like.

Comment: More specifically: the plotting command needs to be inside `renderPlot({ ... })`

Comment: It makes sense. I  modified the code above. but still not working

Answer (score 0):

Using the following `server` worked for me:

```
server = function(input, output, session){

    dataOP <- reactive({
        inFile <- input$file1
        if(is.null(input$file1)){
            return(NULL)
        }
        #Identify_IP(read.table(inFile$datapath))
        list(tble = c(1:20), txt = c(1:10), plt = rnorm(100))
    })

    observeEvent(input$btn,{
        output$what <- renderTable({
            dataOP()$tble
        })
    })

    observeEvent(input$btn1,{
        output$pl <- renderPlot({
            plot(dataOP()$plt)
        })
    })              
}
```

Note that I commented out your function `Identify_IP` and replaced the results with arbitrary values.
If this still doesn't work your problem probably is probably related to this function or with the values returned by the function, respectively.

Comment: I know this is very basic. But how can I call the tble, txt and plt from the fn()? Is it something like this? dfs <- Identify_IP(read.table(inFile$datapath))
        list(tble = dfs$df1 , txt =  dfs$inflection_point, plt = dfs$p) ? My skills are basic in this

Comment: What `fn()`? The reactive `dataOP` returns a list with the named elements `tble`, `ttxt`, and `plt`. Accordingly, you e.g. retrieve `plt` using `dataOP()$plt`.

Comment: And yes, you have to replace my arbitrary values with `list(tble = dfs$df1 , txt = dfs$inflection_point, plt = dfs$p)`

Comment: And `df <- read.table(inFile$datapath)` should work for defining the data.frame, I don't see what you try to do with `Identify_IP ()`

Comment: Identify_IP() is the R script I am trying to call in Shiny. It is a function that returns the list of dataframe, txt, and plot.